# Locally weighted logistic regression

Tags: algorithm, matrix, machine-learning, linear-algebra, regression

I have been trying to implement a locally-weighted logistic regression algorithm in Ruby.  As far as I know, no library currently exists for this algorithm, and there is very little information available, so it's been difficult.

My main resource has been the [dissertation of Dr. Kan Deng](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kdeng/thesis/logistic.pdf), in which he described the algorithm in what I feel is pretty light detail.  My work so far on the library is [here](https://github.com/orthogonal/USCF-Stats/blob/master/lib/LocalLogisticRegression.rb).

I've run into trouble when trying to calculate `B` (beta).  From what I understand, `B` is a `(1+d x 1)` vector that represents the local weighting for a particular point.  After that, `pi` (the probability of a positive output) for that point is the sigmoid function based on the `B` for that point.  To get `B`, use the Newton-Raphson algorithm recursively a certain number of times, probably no more than ten.

Equation 4-4 on page 66, the Newton-Raphson algorithm itself, doesn't make sense to me.  Based on my understanding of what `X` and W are, `(x.transpose * w * x).inverse * x.transpose * w` should be a `(1+d x N)` matrix, which doesn't match up with `B`, which is `(1+d x 1)`.  The only way that would work, then, is if e were a `(N x 1)` vector.

At the top of page 67, under the picture, though, Dr. Deng just says that e is a ratio, which doesn't make sense to me.  Is e Euler's Constant, and it just so happens that that ratio is always 2.718:1, or is it something else?  Either way, the explanation doesn't seem to suggest, to me, that it's a vector, which leaves me confused.

The use of `pi'` is also confusing to me.  Equation 4-5, the derivative of the sigmoid function w.r.t. B, gives a constant multiplied by a vector, or a vector.  From my understanding, though, `pi'` is just supposed to be a number, to be multiplied by w and form the diagonal of the weight algorithm W.

So, my two main questions here are, what is `e` on page 67 and is that the `1xN` matrix I need, and how does `pi'` in equation 4-5 end up a number?

I realize that this is a difficult question to answer, so if there is a good answer then I will come back in a few days and give it a fifty point bounty.  I would send an e-mail to Dr. Deng, but I haven't been able to find out what happened to him after 1997.

If anyone has any experience with this algorithm or knows of any other resources, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Should you only implement Dr.Deng's equation? Have you considered other variants of logistic regression?

Comment: I am looking, in particular, for locally weighted logistic regression.  Ordinary logistic regression is not able to handle multiple intervals, and there are a couple inelegant solutions but the locally weighted algorithm is, I think, smoother and particularly appropriate in my specific application.

Comment: To see a rough example of the kind of chart I'm looking to fit, go to http://www.uscfstats.com/deltas and enter 12842311.  I'd like to figure out a curve to roughly divide green/blue dots and red dots.

Comment: This is a really great question but I don't think you're going to find much help here. You should really consider trying http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/?as=1 or http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks, if a moderator thinks that I would be more likely to find a successful answer on one of those sites then I would be very happy if they would move it for me.  I don't think I have enough reputation to move it myself, if that's something non-moderators on SO can even do.

Comment: @Andrew: You do have enough reputation to flag the question for moderation attention, if you'd like it to be moved. I agree with `megas` that you might get a better answer on a more specialized stackexchange site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is just a version of Logistic regression in which the terms in the log-likelihood function have a multiplicative weight depending on their distance from the point you are trying to classify. I would start by getting familiar with an explanation of logistic regression, such as http://czep.net/stat/mlelr.pdf. The "e" you mention seems to be totally unconnected with Euler's constant - I think he is using e for error.

If you can call Java from Ruby, you may be able to make use of the logistic classifier in Weka described at http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/functions/Logistic.html - this says "Although original Logistic Regression does not deal with instance weights, we modify the algorithm a little bit to handle the instance weights." If nothing else, you could download it and look at its source code. If you do this, note that it is a fairly sophisticated approach - for instance, they check beforehand to see if all the points actually lie pretty much in some subspace of the input space, and project down a few dimensions if they do.

Comment: Thanks, but I understand logistic regression pretty well already.  The parts I am having difficulty with here, I think, are specific to the weighted aspect of this particular algorithm.  I'd be quite happy to be mistaken, though!

Comment: Compare equation 4-2 on page marked 64, which describes standard logistic regression, and equation 4-3 on page marked 66, which describes the weighting. The only difference between them is the weighting w_i, and if you had log-likelihoods instead of likelihoods this turns into a multiplicative factor. So if you understand using Newton-Raphson to fit a normal logistic regression it shouldn't be much of a stretch to understand optimising the objective function with factors of w_i in there as well - just work through the calculations of the first and second derivatives keeping track of w_i.

Comment: Thanks, what about my question about pi'?  Isn't that derivative a vector?

Comment: The pi' in equation 4-5 is the correct derivative of pi, but can't be used to form the diagonal of W as it stands because it already includes (1, xi') which turns up as a column of X' in X'W. If you just want a diagonal that you will multiply by columns of X' you need to drop the (1, xi') from 4.5. For confirmation, compare with equations 11, 16, and 23 in mlelr.pdf (which has n_i almost acting as a weight - it would be one if y_i was defined slightly differently).

Comment: Thanks, I actually did drop the (1, xi') in my implementation, even though it wasn't what he wrote.  It feels sketchy, though, that the proper derivative can't be used in the way that it's supposed to be.

Comment: I think the result is OK but "Using Newton-Raphson algorithm, and through some algebraic manipulations, the maximum likelihood estimate of b can be simplified as" is far too sketchy. The presentation in mlelr.pdf takes a lot more paper but is much easier to follow.

Comment: Thanks, last question, could you tell me a little bit more about what you think e is?
By the way, I really enjoyed your Who-attacked-Whom analysis on your website!

Comment: e is what he says it is at the top of page marked 67: (y_i - pi_i)/pi_i', where pi_i' does not have the vector in 4-5. This matches with equation 11 in mlelr.pdf, with two comments. First of all, to use n_i as a weight you would have to change the definition of y_i here so it becomes for instance z_i * n_i. Second, logistic.pdf divides by pi_i', which is not seen in equation 11, because logistic.pdf has multiplied pi_i' into the W matrix, so it has to cancel it out again to get a derivative as in equation 11 - see also equation 23.